# React Packager fails; must reboot computer every 3-5 times app is reloaded

Tags: react-native

I get the error shown below every 3-5 times I reload the iOS app for React Packager. When restarting Xcode with that error, I see this in the packager window:

```
 "login: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
[Process exited - exit code 1]"
```

The above will not even allow opening any terminal on the Mac.

The only way to make it work is to REBOOT the machine (Running OS X 10.10.5, react-native 0.10 stable and also 0.11 stable)

```
WARN: not opened

Launching Dev Tools...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined

    at exports.execFile (child_process.js:234:15)

    at Object.handle (/Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js:198:7)

    at next (/Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)

    at Object.openStackFrameInEditor [as handle] (/Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js:184:5)

    at next (/Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)

    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js:174:5)

    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)

    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)

    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:893:12)

    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)

 ERROR  spawn /Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/packager/launchChromeDevTools.applescript EAGAIN

{"code":"EAGAIN","errno":"EAGAIN","syscall":"spawn /Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/packager/launchChromeDevTools.applescript","path":"/Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/packager/launchChromeDevTools.applescript","spawnargs":["http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui"]}

Error: spawn /Users/brianmcginnis/learn/react-native2/senior-tab/SeniorTab/node_modules/react-native/packager/launchChromeDevTools.applescript EAGAIN

    at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)

    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)

    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)

    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html
for common problems and solutions.

Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of Native.
Also, if you are running your sim in xcode, you can clear the cache of your project by using command+shift+k with the project stopped.

See if this clears it whenever you have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed latest version of react native, then uninstalled iojs. I installed latest Node.js and everything now works.